# VB6's vbNull equivalent in VB.Net?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, vb6

I would like to discover and use the VB.Net equivalent to replace the `VbNull` value seen in VB6, but I can't find the proper value that represents that null value.

```
Dim formatProvider As NumberFormatInfo = 
    DirectCast(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES").NumberFormat.Clone, NumberFormatInfo)

With formatProvider
    .NumberDecimalSeparator = Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbNull
End With

Dim pi As String = Math.PI.ToString(String.Empty, formatProvider)
```

The `NumberDecimalSeparator` property does not accepts an empty value, but it accpets the `vbNull` value as well and it works perfectlly (the separator is removed), so... I suppose that I can reproduce the same result using the .Net Class library to avoid resort at VB6 things.

I've tried to replace the `vbNull` with those other values, but all give an exception due to the emptiness restriction of the property that I mentioned above:

```
""
String.Empty
ControlChars.NullChar()
DBNull.Value.ToString
Nothing
```

> UPDATE

I also tried these supposed solutions, any of these throws an exception of empty value but instead that it does not give me the expected result because using this as a separator to format a decimal number the number is printed broken.

```
Convert.ToChar(0)
Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0)
New String(Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0))
```

Source: [VB.NET - string of nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140411/vb-net-string-of-nulls)

Comment: .NumberDecimalSeparator = ChrW(&H200B)

Comment: Hans is suggesting using a `zero-length space` - it's a character that is not displayed - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200B/index.htm

Comment: VB6's VbNull doesnt do what you think it does.  It was for comparing the VarType of objects (ala modern GetType).  VbNull would be the equivalent of Nothing in NET.

Comment: @Plutonix, 'Nothing' does not work in the code above, it throws an exception of empty value, while vbNull works perfect.

Comment: I did not say it would, I was explaining what it was.  VB.VBNull is just the constant `1`.  In VB6 it was used something like this: `If VarType(foo) = vbNull` to test for a null object.  `Convert.ToChar(1)` would be the equivalent unprintable control char.  `VarType` and `VbNull` still exist in the NET VB Namespace for compatibility, but the *Zero Width Space*, U+200B suggested would be the clean NET approach.

Comment: @MarkJ as you said, the Hans Passant character solution is not displayed, but it is PROCESSED, what I mean?, that if you iterate the characters of a string formatted with that trick (zero-length char) the unwanted character will be processed, while using vbNull does not happens this, just vbNull is perfect and non-intrusive in the code above, then which is the really equivalent for this in Vb.NET?

Comment: not so sure about "perfect". `.NumberDecimalSeparator = Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbNull` is illegal under Option Strict.  [This shows that](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ghSBPD) the length is the same, just that *what* is stored as char(1) varies.  So I dont know what you mean by PROCESSED. Embedding a control char (1, vbNull) seems very dicey to me.

Comment: "I dont know what you mean by PROCESSED", if you use Hans Passant solution and do a For Each Char Loop in a formatted numeric string then the "empty" character will be processed/displayed, while if you do the same using vbNull it does not.

Comment: actually, the vbNull method is storing a literal `1` in the char array as shown in the fiddle (and easily seen with intellisense). Since they **all** result in strlen 16, it is a matter of *what* is stored. The VS immediate window shows differently than the fiddle. There is always: `strNum.Where(Function(x) Char.IsDigit(x)).ToArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trigger is correct vbNull is a constant, but its value is defined thusly: `Public Const vbNull As VariantType = VariantType.Null`

Please see [Microsoft Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/Constants.cs)

Answer (score 2):

vbnull is a datatype and not what you think it is. From Object Viewer (VB6 or Office VBA Editor press F2)

```
Const vbNull = 1
    Member of VBA.VbVarType
    Return value constant for VarType
```

Things you may have it confused with

```
Const vbNullChar = ""
    Member of VBA.Constants
    Basic constant for a single Null character (ASCII value 0); equivalent to Chr$(0)

Const vbNullString = ""
    Member of VBA.Constants
    Constant for  use when calling external procedures requiring a string whose value is zero
```